# Unable to get "flat" endcapStyle to work for st_buffer in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I am currently creating a table of sfc linestrings using lat/lon coordinates, and drawing a buffer. However, I am unable to get the endcapstyle = "FLAT" argument to work. I would like this to work as I need the buffer to not extend past the end points of the lines.  What am I missing?

```
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(tidyverse)


## random coordinates for example
df_tbl <- tibble::tribble(
  ~lat,   ~lon,   ~lat2,   ~lon2,
  39.977917887303626, -105.28350982984472, 40.026678120413961, -105.20312377997453,
  39.934422269952776, -105.25986687400055, 39.902061443935025, -105.28605599432022)

## create points
beg_t <- df_tbl %>% select(lon, lat) %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)  
end_t <- df_tbl %>% select(lon2, lat2) %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon2", "lat2"), crs = 4326)  

# combine start and end geometries
cbind(beg_t,end_t) -> points_ready 

# create linestrings

line_segments <- points_ready %>% 
  mutate(
    path = st_sfc(purrr::map2(
      .x = geometry, 
      .y = geometry.1, 
      .f = ~{st_union(c(.x, .y)) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")}
    ),
    crs = 4326)) 

## try to use the FLAT endCapStyles
line_segments$buffer <- st_buffer(line_segments$path, dist = 2000, endCapStyle = "FLAT")
mapview(line_segments$path) + mapview(line_segments$buffer)  ## the buffers are not flat at the ends
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endCapStyle will work only in GEOS settings = it is not compatible with {s2} world of spherical operations. You can either turn off {s2} processing entirely, or re-project to a planar CRS.

In the following code I am using the second approach, going for Web Mercator (EPSG 3857).

Also I am choosing to create the buffered lines as a separate object, since the points and lines are in WGS84, and I don't quite like mixing CRSes in a single object (the active / non active geometry feature of {sf} should handle it, but it does not *feel* right).

```r
library(sf)
library(mapview)
library(tidyverse)


## random coordinates for example
df_tbl <- tibble::tribble(
  ~lat,   ~lon,   ~lat2,   ~lon2,
  39.977917887303626, -105.28350982984472, 40.026678120413961, -105.20312377997453,
  39.934422269952776, -105.25986687400055, 39.902061443935025, -105.28605599432022)

## create points
beg_t <- df_tbl %>% select(lon, lat) %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)  
end_t <- df_tbl %>% select(lon2, lat2) %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon2", "lat2"), crs = 4326)  

# combine start and end geometries
cbind(beg_t,end_t) -> points_ready 

# create linestrings

line_segments <- points_ready %>% 
  mutate(
    path = st_sfc(purrr::map2(
      .x = geometry, 
      .y = geometry.1, 
      .f = ~{st_union(c(.x, .y)) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")}
    ),
    crs = 4326)) 

## try to use the FLAT endCapStyles
buffered_lines <- line_segments$path %>% 
  st_transform("EPSG:3857") %>% # to force GEOS processing
  st_buffer(endCapStyle = "FLAT",
            dist = 2000)

mapview(line_segments$path) + mapview(buffered_lines)
```

[image: two buffers with flat ends]